# Breakup of prediction in terms of individual features

Tags: python, data-science, prediction, modeling, feature-selection

We have applied multiple machine learning models like light ***GBM, random forest, elastic net, XGBoost*** etc for prediction. The requirement is to dis-aggregate the predicted value (each prediction) in terms of input features.[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDcOZ.png)

There are continuous as well as categorical input variables. Categorical variables are more in number in the data.

**e.g for requirement**: say I have a prediction `y = 1000$` and that there are three input features `x1`, `x2` and `x3`. Is there a way to express the predicted value (1000$) contributed as 400$ by `x1`, 300$ by `x2` and 300$ by `x3`.

**Methods tried**: Feature importance from random forest to attribute percentage contribution from each input variable. This was not giving meaningful results.

**LIME and Shapley**: LIME provides a local intercept value that is not meaningful in the scenario under consideration. Shapley provides a quantification of deviation from an expected value in terms of individual features, which was also not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a linear relationship between your features and your target. The best solution would be of course to fit a linear model!

You said you tried **elastic net**, which is actually a regularized linear regression. If the model performance was satisfying, you can use the coefficients of the linear regression to compute the contribution. Indeed, the model will be:

[image: eq0]

So [image: x1] contributed by [image: eq1] (or just [image: b1], depending on what you mean by "contributing") to [image: y]. Note that in the notion of "contribution" you should try to make sense of the intercept value [image: b0].

If the performance of the "basic" linear model is not good enough you can do some feature engineering (using squares of variables or other transformation as an example), look at [the generalized linear model or the generalized additive model](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/extend-lm.html) but this will be really specific to you problem.

Now if fitting a linear model does not work, it means that you cannot find a global linear relationship between your target and dependent features. You need to approximate a local linear relationship, but it might not always work or give the expected result. LIME with a linear explanation model seems to be a good option, maybe you can investigate a bit more why it didn't work well for you.